# Populate select box with json data from laravel db query

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, laravel-5

i have a html select box that needs to be populated using jquery ajax with select options that come from a php (Laravel) database query. I tried many approaches but no result, i only get 'undefined' as result. 
The Laravel script:

```
public function loturi($articol) {
$loturi = DB::select("select mgla_lotto from MG_V_DispoLottiBarcode d
join MG_AnaArt art on art.MGAA_Id = d.MGAA_Id join MG_LottiAnag  l on         
l.MGLA_Id = d.MGLA_Id where MGAA_MBDC_Classe IN ('SEM','FIN') and mbmg_id = 55 
and mgaa_matricola in (select  child.MGAA_Matricola component
from DB_Legami join MG_AnaArt  child on child.MGAA_Id = DBLG_Com_MGAA_Id
join MG_AnaArt  p on p.MGAA_Id = DBLG_MGAA_Id
where p.MGAA_Matricola = '$articol')  and mgla_datacreazione > '2014-01-01'
group by mgla_lotto having sum(dispo) > 0");
return compact('loturi');
}
```

The result is this:

```
{"loturi":[{"mgla_lotto":"1282\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1316\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1339\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1349\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1354\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1404\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1405\/15"},{"mgla_lotto":"1412\/15"}]}
```

The jquery script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cod").change(function(){
var cod_articol = $("#cod").val();
$.ajax ({
url: "/internal/" + cod_articol ,
datatype: "json",
success: function(data) {
$.each(data, function(value){
$("#lot").append('<option id="' + value.index + '">' + value.name +   
'</option>');
      })
     }
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: Do you want as 1282 as index and 15 as name from `1282/15` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here is your answer.

change

```
$.each(data, function(value){
```

to

```
$.each(data.loturi, function(value){
```

and use below syntax

```
$.each(data.loturi, function( index, value ){
    $("#lot").append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value.mgla_lotto  + '</option>');
}
```

Go to the link to see the example i have made for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/ovht7fkh/2/

Comment: I seem to get closer, now i get a list of select options equal to the number of query results but they are all [object Object]

Comment: Please see the edited answer. There is the solution for your code.

Comment: will you appreciate/accept the answer if it works for you?

Comment: it is also useless to use id attribute inside of option